# Keras sequential model in Django - preserve session?

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, keras

I do not know how I can "preserve" the graph/session of my Keras model inside a Django app that runs as a server.

I've build Keras sequential model `DeepModel` which works fine as a standalone Python module. But now I want to embed it in Django application where I defined the following handler for the model:

```
# instantiated by Django app
class DeepModelManager:

def __init__(self, params):

    self.graph = tf.Graph()
    self.sess = tf.Session()
    K.set_session(self.sess)
    with self.sess.as_default():
        self.instance = DeepModel(params)
        self.model = self.instance.build()

        optimizer = Adam()
        loss = "categorical_crossentropy"
        metrics = ["accuracy"]
        self.model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=metrics)

def train(self):
    X = ...
    y = ...

    K.set_session(self.sess)
    with self.sess.as_default():
        H = self.model.fit(X, y, epochs=20)
```

The process works in the following way:

- first Django app awaits an init request from external client, then it instantiates `DeepModelManager` (as a `views` module variable) which instantiates/builds/compiles the Keras `DeepModel`
- then Django app awaits a train request which should trigger the above `train` function i.e. model fitting

But whenever `train` method is run, I am constantly getting error

`ValueError: Tensor("training/Adam/Const:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("sub:0", shape=(), dtype=float32).`

which I suspect is due to the fact that the TensorFlow session (or the graph) is somehow cleared between model initialization and training. This is why I tried to play with `tf.Session()` and `tf.Graph()` (in standalone `DeepModel` version I'm not touching it) but it doesn't help.